# Paraview visualization help ("density/mist" plot?!)

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, paraview

I am trying to visualize a data set (x,y,z,scalar) in comma separated values format.  The style I want to recreate is something like a transparent 3d heat map.  The value of scalar at coordinate (x,y,z) will determine the "mist density".  No idea what the name of the style is.  Links below give examples of what I mean:

https://www.paraview.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/densityoverlay.png

or

http://www.scidac.gov/Conference2006/speaker_abs/AhrensPic.jpg

Any references would be most useful as I am new to data visualizing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Point Volume Interpolate` filter with `Kernel` set to `GaussianKernel`.